# 502 Bad gateway Error for nginx deployments if istio automatic injection enabled into namespace

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, servicemesh

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/41233

I have one namespace 'eshop-bg-poc' into kubernetes cluster and I have enabled istio automatic injection also into namespace. I have one nginx under service name 'eshop-bgpoc-nginx' running with minimum replicas 3 and maximum replicas 5 . but if i redeployed nginx than for few seconds i received 502 badgateway request on nginx .

I tested same scenario by disable istio automatic injection into same namespace . It worked fine for redeployment nginx not able to see 502 bad gateway request.

Note : I haven't applied any virtual services and destination rule for nginx

Comment: if you dont need side car proxy for nginx pod alone you can add annotation sidecar.istio.io/inject with value false for nginx pods.  is there any specific requirement for nginx pod to have istio configuration?

Comment: if i disable sidecar injection into nginx than virtual services stop working for below services .       my application  structue is like      nginx(no virtual services) -> ui(virtual services) -> bf(virtual services).  virtual services logic apply on ui is stop working

Comment: If I am not wrong the flow should be nginx (outside from application namespace) to istio enabled application namespace. nginx itself can be an reverse proxy or ingress controller.

Comment: No , nginx is not outside application namespace , it is into same namespace

Comment: Please deploy nginx outside application namespace

Comment: if i move nginx outside of namespace issue will not be resolved than routing of traffic will stop working